# Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView ...' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to change the font size of `TextView`'s when the `MainActivity` starts, but I am facing a `NullPointerException` error in this case!

Here is the Log:

```
08-10 05:05:51.821 2363-2363/com.twitter.i_droidi.notah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.twitter.i_droidi.notah, PID: 2363
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter.i_droidi.notah/com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.NotesAdapter$NotesViewHolder.noteTitle' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.NotesAdapter$NotesViewHolder.noteTitle' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:153)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder myHolder;
    private SharedPreferences fontSizePrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
        ...

        fontSizePrefs = getSharedPreferences(Preferences.PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

...
...
}

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        switch(fontSizePrefs.getInt("font_size", -1))
            {
                case 0:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) 19.5);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) 12.75);
                    return;

                case 1:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
                    return;

                case 2:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                    return;

                case 3:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                    return;

                case 4:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
                    return;

                case 5:
                    myHolder.noteTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
                    myHolder.noteBody.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
                    myHolder.noteDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
                    return;
            }
    }
```

NotesAdapter.java:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Notes> {

    private final Context context;
    private Realm realm;

    protected NotesAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public NotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        return new NotesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        realm = RealmController.getInstance().getRealm();

        final Notes note = getItem(position);
        final NotesViewHolder myHolder = (NotesViewHolder) holder;

        myHolder.noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        myHolder.noteBody.setText(note.getBody());
        myHolder.noteDate.setText(note.getDate());
        myHolder.card.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                final RealmResults<Notes> results = realm.where(Notes.class).findAll();

                Notes note = results.get(position);
                final String title = note.getTitle();

                AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                deleteDialog.setTitle(R.string.delete_a_note_title);
                deleteDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_a_note_msg) + title + context.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_a_note_msg2));
                deleteDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
                deleteDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        results.deleteFromRealm(position);
                        realm.commitTransaction();

                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
                        obj.updateView();

                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.note_deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // DO NOT DO ANYTHING.
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        myHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewNote.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if(getRealmAdapter() != null)
        {
            return getRealmAdapter().getCount();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    protected static class NotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private CardView card;
        protected TextView noteTitle;
        protected TextView noteBody;
        protected TextView noteDate;

        protected NotesViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            card = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            noteTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
            noteBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_body);
            noteDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note_date);
        }
    }
}
```

card_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout_of_cards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="19.5sp"
                android:textColor="#212121"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:fontFamily="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:linksClickable="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/note_title"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:fontFamily="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12.75sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/note_body"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:textColor="#212121"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please take note that `onStart` is executed before any other code of your Activity. Therefore, the ViewHolder will be null anyways.

Comment: Additionally, never do this --> `MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();`. Activities never need to be `new`-ed

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your notes. I added `card_view.xml`. Is there any way to change the font size?! I tried `onStart();` with another activities and it works without any problem.

Comment: I don't know why you want to modify something that is loaded after `onStart` from within `onStart`... Why can't you just set that stuff from `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, solved by editing `onBindViewHolder` as you said.